# Xcode 4.5 (iOS) - Link projects (library and app)

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5, dependencies, xcode4.3

I have 2 projects in the same workspace. One is iOS library and the other is iOS app.

Is there an easy way to get the app project use the library proejct?
I have one requirement: Whenever i make changes in the library project i want them to automatically affect the app project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't copy the Library project into your app project. Instead make a reference of Library project into app Project.

Whenever you import Library project into app project OR you just drag n drop it... then use reference of Library instead of copying of resources into app project...

this way whenever you made change in library project... it will automatically reflected in app project.

**EDIT**

Whenever you drag n drop a file in Xcode project....
You are asked 2 options...

1. Copy items into Destination group's folder.
2. Folder's option.

For option 1. **De-Select** the checkbox. which will create a reference for that file.

For option 2. you can do whatever you want....

Comment: i didn't understand what you're saying. can you give a more 1,2,3... explanation ?

Comment: I think i got you... i didn't think about copying all files. I tried to drag the library project over the app project but it still doesn't build.

Comment: i saw it... that's what i did. doesn't compile/build. thanks for your quick answer!

Comment: Make sure that you must have firstly removed the previously copied Library files from app project. Then make sure that what ever you are referencing has proper structured same as what you were doing while copying of resource. What I mean is that if you have some folder structured then see that whether it is referenced properly or not...